# Splitcontainer flowlayoutpanel or autosized panel (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, autosize, flowlayoutpanel, splitcontainer

Forms in an application I'm working on with a team have a datagridview as main component (it should take up most of the size), but there are other components. there is a horizontal splitcontainer to split them, but I was wondering how to make the top panel resize to its contents. Unfortunately, the panels in a splitcontainer don't have an `AutoSize` property...

Here are two images to show what we need:
[image: image1]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/8d141b69c63b0d3ac8aebf9129bb77e25ee4a75086cfa6595c4510041fda1fa66g.jpg))</sub>

[image: image2]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/56d959d2a9f99b71af16f7ab3eb5833874e8583f7b15bd1df16aafaa7313a7066g.jpg))</sub>

As you can see, the top panel of the splitcontainer should adjust to the size of its contents. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant "horizontal" split container based on your image.

You can try achieving this manually by using the `ControlAdded` event of the top panel:

```
Public Class Form1

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance = SmallPanel.Height
  End Sub

  Private Sub SplitContainer1_Panel1_ControlAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ControlEventArgs) Handles SplitContainer1.Panel1.ControlAdded
    SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance += e.Control.Height
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim addPanel As New Panel
    addPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    addPanel.Size = New Size(SplitContainer1.Panel1.ClientSize.Width, 100)
    addPanel.Location = New Point(0, SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance)
    addPanel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Right
    SplitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(addPanel)
  End Sub

End Class
```

SmallPanel is a panel I placed in Panel1 of the SplitContainer and added a button in their to add more panels.

Comment: That would work but I was hoping for something that automatically does it. There is only actually one control in the upper panel, a usercontrol. That control has a flowlayout panel in it, and I would have liked the splitcontainer top panel to adjust its size to the size of the flowlayout panel in the usercontrol... Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester If the FLP is in the UC, then you obviously need to have that UC resizing itself already (that's what it sounds like).  Just hook into the UC's resize event to set the `SplitterDistance`